# Why can't game be easily adapted to VR

Tags: virtual-reality

I've had this question for some time now, but never got around to asking it. Why can't games be easily adapted to VR? I understand some games in which animations change viewpoint would nauseate the gamer, but in games like CSGO, where the only thing that would be difficult might be scoping in and head bob, why can't games simply go through some predetermined algorithm to split the view for VR, and add in code for VR headset control and VR controllers? I assume there is some reason, but I can't think why.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If your game character moves forward in VR without you physically moving, your brain will get confused and you will get motion sick. Most VR games get around this by teleporting you so you don't really "move", but this requires the games to be made for VR.

Comment: This helps clarify. Thanks. However, aren't there devices used similar to a treadmill such as the virtuix omni that could be used? I realize that this is a more difficult scenario, and reaches a narrower audience, but I think it would be worth it for companies to make a separate edition of their games for VR that include some tag saying they are to be used with omnidirectional treadmills.

Comment: Right now VR and omni treadmills are brand new and thus don't really won't have a wide enough reach for it to be worth investing in. They're also really expensive.